# What is the most efficient way to copy an externally provided buffer to bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ctypes

I am interfacing to an external library using ctypes. This library returns to me a binary buffer. The interface looks like this:

```
int getBuff(unsigned char **buf, int *len);
```

The library also exports a deallocator so that I can free the buffer when I am done with it, but that aspect presents no problems to me, so I don't think we need to cover it.

In my ctypes code I am representing the `buf` argument as `c_void_p`. I would like to copy this buffer into a bytes object as efficiently as possible.

At the moment I have:

```
data = bytes(bytearray(ctypes.cast(buf, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte*len.value))[0]))
```

where `buf` is `c_void_p` and `len` is `c_int`.

As I understand it, this performs two copies. Once to the bytearray object, and then again to the bytes object.

How can I do this with only a single copy?

My current efforts have concentrated on Python 2, but in due course I will need to support this for Python 3 as well.

Comment: On Python 3, you should be able to just remove the `bytearray` call.

Comment: Why are you using a `c_void_p` with a cast instead of just `buf = POINTER(c_char)`? Then `getBuff(byref(buf), byref(len))` and `data = buf[:len.value]`.

Comment: @eryksun: Huh. You can slice a ctypes pointer? News to me.

Comment: @user2357112, it has to be a [`_Pointer` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._Pointer). The simple pointer types (`c_void_p`, `c_char_p`, `c_wchar_p`) subclass `_SimpleCData` and only have a `value`. But I see I have a typo in my first comment. I'm missing the call to instantiate it as `buf = POINTER(c_char)()`.

Comment: @eryksun Why? Because I knew no better. Thanks, as always, for your knowledgeable contributions.

Comment: @eryksun Brain freeze on my part really, mostly due to my lack of fluency in Python and ctypes. Also contributing to this is that the C library is really a delphi library written by me and I'd used `Pointer` which is essentially `void*`. Lazy of me. I wrote the question in C to make it more accessible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently you can slice a ctypes pointer. Not `c_void_p`, `c_char_p`, or `c_wchar_p`, but `POINTER` types work. For a `POINTER(c_char)`, slicing it gives you `bytes`:

```
data = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char).from_buffer(buf)[:len.value]
```

Thanks to eryksun for bringing that up. Also, it's not clear why `buf` is a `c_void_p` instead of already being a `POINTER(c_char)`. (For a `POINTER(c_char)`, the code would be just `buf[:len.value]`.)

---

For getting `bytes` from a general object that supports the buffer protocol, `memoryview(...).tobytes()` involves one less copy than `bytes(bytearray(...))`:

```
data = memoryview(ctypes.cast(buf, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte*len.value))[0]).tobytes()
```

This is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

---

Keep in mind that the `buf` here needs to be a pointer to the buffer, not a pointer to a pointer to the buffer. `getBuff` takes a pointer to a pointer (so probably `byref(buf)`).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah the double pointer is so that the library can return the pointer to the caller. But in my ctypes code buf is the pointer to the buffer.

Comment: @eryksun: I took a look, and wow, `cast` actually is an FFI call instead of a regular built-in or Python function, and it actually is surprisingly slow. Over a microsecond per call on the environment I tested it in just for the `cast` call alone, compared to about 67 nanoseconds for the pointer slicing and about 285 nanoseconds for `memoryview(x).tobytes()` (with a 10-element test array).

Comment: @eryksun: Did you mean `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)`, or is there some API weirdness that means we should actually be using `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)`?